# How Do I See All Of The Tags Labelled 'Bounty' Launchpad-wide?

Tags: launchpad

Just looking on launchpad for all of the bounties that are available.
I am here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bugs?field.tag=bounty

My question is how do I see all of the bounties that are on launchpad under that **'bounty' tag** ?

Answer (score 1):

Just search for all bugs in all projects, and then narrow the search with the bounty tag. Shortened URL to trim the fat from advanced search comes out as:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/+bugs?field.tag=bounty